# Wordpress Multisite + Erros with URLS and ADMIN

Tags: multisite, redirect, domain-mapping, dns

Greetings Stackexchange.

Recently i have made a new WP site for a client - which is not a multisite. 
Without my knowlegde their previous site was a multisite. The site i have made is a new edition of their "main branch business", and the others are "sub business'".

MAIN SITE(Domain main site): www.masterbusiness.

SUB SITE: www.subbusiness.com & www.subbusiness.com/nl.

Their IT department, have made a DNS redirect from their old solution to our webhost servers. After that their remaining subsites of course broke. 
The main site is the one that redirects to our webhost.

So i have been allowed access to their host backend and have inspected the setup.

The problem is now how i should approach this problem? I have tried to change the DOMAIN MAIN SITE to a sub domain instead - and of course changed the URL in the database. As expected this does still not solve the problem.

The former developer has used the plugin Wordpess MU Domain Mapping to controll the redirects to the respective site.

SUMMARY

THE PROBLEM: 
After redirect of main url/page to a new webhost the subsites have broken urls, images and cannot access admin.

THE DESIRED SULUTION: To make one of the "sub sites" to the main site.

If you need any more information please let me know.

Comment: at the new host, put .htaccess redirects in that point all traffic for subbusiness.com to masterbusiness.com

Answer (score 0):

Kindly tell me the following points clearly.

1. You have a sub domain in your master. Ex. test.com/nl. So the sub domain DNS , A record pointed to same pointer, Conform with Cpanel or else. The offline server Web server / Apache having the issue. So Kindly check it.
2. You have Log file, So conform with your web server having access for the third Parity IP mapping. Some web provider aren't interested.

95% issue with DNS . Kindly check it.